# Converting JPG images for input to scikit learn SVM classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

I have a bunch of training images (.jpg format) that I want to give as training input to scikit learn's SVM classifier. Any idea what's the preferred way to doing this?

For example, in [the example here](http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/auto_examples/plot_digits_classification.html) the image data is loaded from a predefined set and converted to a format that the SVM classifier understands in the following steps.

```
# The digits dataset
digits = datasets.load_digits()

# To apply an classifier on this data, we need to flatten the image, to
# turn the data in a (samples, feature) matrix:
n_samples = len(digits.images)
data = digits.images.reshape((n_samples, -1))
```

My question is if I've my own set of images that I want to load as a training set to the SVM classifier how should I go about converting those images into a format that the classifier will understand.

My developing on OS-X (Mavericks) but I'll run the actual code on Linux (Ubuntu)

Thanks

Comment: You want shell scripts? Python scripts? What is your OS?

Comment: I don't want shell scripts. I'm coding in python on OS-X (Mavericks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use standard python libraries for working with images, like [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) or it's fork [Pillow](http://python-imaging.github.io/). It should be straightforward to obtain numpy arrays of bytes from that.

As for feature extraction I guess Thorsten has better tools.

Comment: Oh, o.k., I didn't realize that the reading process already was you concern. The original question was somehow unclear. Thus, I'd recommend a combination of @jb s answer and mine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use DeCAF / nolearn / convnet for this task. See [this page](http://pythonhosted.org/nolearn/convnet.html) for an example.

Comment: The link is dead.